# Jetty ServletTester class for Version 9.4.34.v20201102

Tags: java, testing, dependencies, jetty

I'm currently looking into testing jetty servlets. I found the  `org.eclipse.jetty.testing.ServletTester` class in [some old documentation](https://download.eclipse.org/jetty/8.1.17.v20150415/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/testing/ServletTester.html)  (just by random searching on the web),  but it seems to be removed in newer versions.

Is there a replacement for it, and if yes, where can i find it?

If there is no replacement, I would be happy to hear about different ways to accomplish the goal of testing servlets!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class `org.eclipse.jetty.testing.ServletTester` is the old Jetty 7 and Jetty 8 ServletTester.

It can be found in the following maven artifacts ...

- https://search.maven.org/search?q=fc:org.eclipse.jetty.testing.ServletTester

The newer `org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletTester` (note the package change) is available for Jetty 9.x, Jetty 10.x, and Jetty 11.x in the following artifacts ...

- https://search.maven.org/search?q=fc:org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletTester

Standard maven repository behaviors here, as the class is not a runtime class, it sits in the `tests` jar (also on maven central).

Example:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
  <version>9.4.35.v20201120</version>
  <classifier>tests</classifier>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I have now found the [Source Code](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.34.v20201102/jetty-servlet/src/test/java/org/eclipse/jetty/servlet/ServletTester.java) of the ServletTester class, but maven doesnt download it after including the dependency in my `pom.xml`. I assume this is due to the source being in the `test` directory, not the `src` directory. How can I fix this? (If the answer is to big for a simple comment, I'll create a new question)

Comment: I updated the answer, the class is on maven central (otherwise it wouldn't be found by search.maven.org).  Just use the tests classified artifact for that maven coordinate space.